# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

Want to use Firebase for sending PUSH and so retrieving device token. And so went though this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). But get the following error when want to sync `gradle`. What is the problem? Pressing `try again` but has no effect.

`Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: On that page you linked to... *Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager*

Comment: @Janos accept my answer if its solved your problem.

Comment: Are we going to have to solve this everytime Google publishes new play services library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Android SDK Manager and install the latest version of below two libraries

1-Google Play Services

2-Google Repository